# Sort one array by columns of another array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have two arrays, `a` and `b`, as follows:

```
a = array([[19.        ,  0.84722222],
           [49.        ,  0.86111111],
           [54.        ,  0.86666667],
           [42.        ,  0.9       ],
           [ 7.        ,  0.91111111],
           [46.        ,  0.99722222]])

b = array([[46.        ,  0.46944444],
       [49.        ,  0.59722222],
       [19.        ,  0.63611111],
       [42.        ,  0.72777778],
       [54.        ,  0.74722222],
       [ 7.        ,  0.98888889]])
```

I would like to sort `b` so that its first column matches the first column of array `a`.
My output should be

```
b = array([[19.        ,  0.63611111],
           [49.        ,  0.59722222],
           [54.        ,  0.74722222],
           [42.        ,  0.72777778],
           [ 7.        ,  0.98888889]
           [46.        ,  0.46944444]])
```

Comment: `b[np.where(a[:,None] == b[None, :])[1]]`

Comment: Nice question. You're allowed to change your selected answer by the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am supposing *a* and *b* have the same dimension and that the the first column contains the same set of elements.

```
import numpy as np

def same_order(a, b):
    new_pos = np.full(shape = a.shape[0], fill_value = -1)
    for i in range(new_pos.shape[0]):
        new_pos[np.where(a[:,0] == b[i,0])[0][0]] = i
    return b[new_pos]
```

Comment: This is not a very good way to do it because it discards the benefits of numpy.

Comment: indeed, nevertheless if you do not speculate on performances then it is good enough

Answer (score 6):

Conceptually you want to get the indices that will turn column zero of `b` into column zero of `a`. Imagine doing `argsort` on both. This will give you the indices to go from `a` or `b` to a sorted state. Now if you apply the inverse operation to the `a` index, it will tell you how to get from sorted back to `a`. As it happens, `argsort` is its own inverse. So I present you the following:

```
index = np.argsort(b[:, 0])[np.argsort(np.argsort(a[:, 0]))]
b = b[index, ...]
```

This is `O(n log n)` time complexity because of the three sorts. The other solutions here are `O(n^2)` since they perform a linear search for each index.

Comment: ... I was just going after an `argsort` solution .

Comment: @wwii. Nice. Nothing like a triple argsort to keep you interested :)

Comment: hmm, mine doesn't work if there are *duplicate* values in the first column. deleting..

Answer (score 0):

I think the most conceptually simple way to approach this is with a simple merge/join. Piggy-backing on your array definitions of `a` and `b`...

```
import pandas as pd

# convert arrays to Pandas DataFrames
df_a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['id', 'values_a'])
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['id', 'values_b'])

# Merge in the values from b, into the table (and order) in a
df_merged = df_a.merge(df_b, how='left', on='id')

# Here's the two columns you want (in desired order) as a 2d numpy array via .values
answer = df_merged[['id', 'values_b']].values
```

...I find using DataFrames for these sorts of tasks makes everything clearer and debugging much easier whenever I encounter unexpected results